# Will changing IP address cause any integration or security problems?

Tags: web-hosting, ecommerce, ip-address, migration

We have an ecommerce website that uses PayPal and SagePay to process payments. Our host moved our site to a new server recently, resulting a change of IP address. This caused SagePay to temporarily stop working until we registered the new IP address with them.

Will the change of IP address cause any other technical or security issues?

I'm not worried about SEO, I'm more concerned about technical/integration problems. It's a Wordpress site and we use Woocommerce, Analytics, Adwords, LiveChat Inc, SagePay, PayPal, Zapier, Salesforce/Formstack, Facebook/LinkedIn tracking codes etc.

Comment: See also: [Would changing IP addresses affect my SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49341/would-changing-ip-addresses-affect-my-seo)

Comment: How can we possibly know the answer to this?  You will have to check which APIs need to have an IP address authorised and update them.  You _might_ only discover this when something breaks.  If it hasn't broken by now with the new IP address then it likely won't.

Answer (score 1):

As far as security issues sometimes when you are running a CMS and you've gotten a new ip address that ip is not always free of blacklisting.  I worked at a web host for years and from time to time I would see a customer have mail delivery problems because the ip address they got was blacklisted because of the previous owner and the ip was subsequently recycled without it being delisted.  It is a good idea to check the ip on mxtoolbox.com because mail delivery problems with php are not always apparent because there is no return path unless you put it in your code.